# pgfplots: How to Define Variables with Numbers taken from a File?

Tags: pgfplots, datatool

While working on a scientific topic, I wondered if the following is possible:
I want to plot several exponential curves using the `\addplot` command. The specialty lies in the fact that I need the exponents not to be hard-coded, but read from a text file! How could this be accomplished?
I've created a MWE to clarify want I want:

```
%% MWE for SX: Defining variables with numbers taken from a file
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%% Use only sans-serif fonts; change to serif if desired
\renewcommand*\sfdefault{phv}
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{arevmath}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}
\usetikzlibrary{spy, backgrounds}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%% To read variables from file
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\newlength\figurewidth
\newlength\figureheight
\newlength\marksize

\begin{document}
%% Width and height of the output figure, adapt as necessary
\setlength{\figurewidth}{13cm}
\setlength{\figureheight}{8cm}
\setlength{\marksize}{2.4pt}
\setlength{\linewidth}{1pt}

%% Define the file in here, as whole files cannot be uploaded to Tex.SE
\begin{filecontents}{LsqExponents.csv}
4.012,3.456,2.345
\end{filecontents}
%% Now read these three values from the file
\DTLloaddb[noheader, keys={b_annu, b_rest, b_stra}]{LsqExponents}{LsqExponents.csv}
%\DTLdisplaydb{LsqExponents}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\large]

\begin{axis}[%
width=\figurewidth,
height=\figureheight,
scale only axis,
xmin=0.05,
xmax=0.5,
xtick={0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5},
xlabel={$\text{T G S } \gamma_\mathrm{g} \text{ (-)}$},
%xmajorgrids,
ymin=0,
ymax=0.12,
ylabel={$\text{G R P } h_\mathrm{g} \text{ (-)}$},
yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed,
/pgf/number format/precision=2,
/pgf/number format/fixed zerofill},
%ymajorgrids,
name=plot1,
legend pos=north west,
legend style={anchor=north west,draw=black,fill=white,legend cell align=left, rounded corners=2pt, nodes={inner sep=4pt,text depth=0pt}}
]
%% Fits and functions
\addplot [color=cyan, solid, domain=0:0.5] {x^4.567};
\addlegendentry{Original TD Fit};

\addplot [color=magenta, dashed, domain=0:0.5] {x^3.456};
\addlegendentry{TD-like Fit for Rest};

\addplot [color=black, dashed, domain=0:0.5] {x^2.345};
\addlegendentry{TD-like Fit for Stra};

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

As you can see, the exponents are now hard-coded (lines 65-71), but should be float variables, taken from the csv file (which is generated by another program beforehand)! I fumbled a bit with the great [`datatool`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datatool) package, but I'm not sure how or even if it's possible to employ it for my needs. The `\DTLdisplaydb{LsqExponents}` command fails, that's why it's commented out in the MWE.

So I guess the solution consists of two steps:

1. Getting the three numbers as individual variables in LaTeX/Tikz.
2. Replacing the hard-coded exponents with these variables.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I make an implementation using my `readarray` package, which reads space-separated data.  Key lines are

```
\begin{filecontents*}{LsqExponents.ssv}
4.012 3.456 2.345
\end{filecontents*}
%% Now read these three values from the file
\readdef{LsqExponents.ssv}{\mydatadef}
\readArrayij{\mydatadef}{mydata}{1}
```

What this does is read the file contents into a `\def` named `\mydatadef`.  Then, I read from `\mydatadef` and sort it into a 2-D array structure named `mydata` with column width = 1 (thus, a 1-D array effectively).  The data values are accessed with `\arrayij{mydata}{<row value>}{1}`

```
%% MWE for SX: Defining variables with numbers taken from a file
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%% Use only sans-serif fonts; change to serif if desired
\renewcommand*\sfdefault{phv}
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{arevmath}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}
\usetikzlibrary{spy, backgrounds}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%% To read variables from file
\usepackage{readarray}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\newlength\figurewidth
\newlength\figureheight
\newlength\marksize

\begin{document}
%% Width and height of the output figure, adapt as necessary
\setlength{\figurewidth}{13cm}
\setlength{\figureheight}{8cm}
\setlength{\marksize}{2.4pt}
\setlength{\linewidth}{1pt}

%% Define the file in here, as whole files cannot be uploaded to Tex.SE
\begin{filecontents*}{LsqExponents.ssv}
4.012 3.456 2.345
\end{filecontents*}
%% Now read these three values from the file
\readdef{LsqExponents.ssv}{\mydatadef}
\readArrayij{\mydatadef}{mydata}{1}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\large]

\begin{axis}[%
width=\figurewidth,
height=\figureheight,
scale only axis,
xmin=0.05,
xmax=0.5,
xtick={0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5},
xlabel={$\text{T G S } \gamma_\mathrm{g} \text{ (-)}$},
%xmajorgrids,
ymin=0,
ymax=0.12,
ylabel={$\text{G R P } h_\mathrm{g} \text{ (-)}$},
yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed,
/pgf/number format/precision=2,
/pgf/number format/fixed zerofill},
%ymajorgrids,
name=plot1,
legend pos=north west,
legend style={anchor=north west,draw=black,fill=white,legend cell align=left, rounded corners=2pt, nodes={inner sep=4pt,text depth=0pt}}
]
%% Fits and functions
\addplot [color=cyan, solid, domain=0:0.5] {x^\arrayij{mydata}{1}{1}};
\addlegendentry{Original TD Fit};

\addplot [color=magenta, dashed, domain=0:0.5] {x^\arrayij{mydata}{2}{1}};
\addlegendentry{TD-like Fit for Rest};

\addplot [color=black, dashed, domain=0:0.5] {x^\arrayij{mydata}{3}{1}};
\addlegendentry{TD-like Fit for Stra};

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that should work. As long as I remember correctly which variable represents which value.