# How to create legend in loop using parameters from text file with PGFPlots?

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I have parameter in a text file and I would like to create legend using those parameters.
I have tried to read data with

```
\pgfplotstableread{param.txt}{\myparams}
```

and get specific parameter with

```
\pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{0}\of{\myparams}
```

and then set macro with

```
\pgfmathsetmacro\parA{\pgfplotsretval}
```

and the create legend entry with

```
\addlegendentry{\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=5,use comma]{\parA}}
```

I have tried to do this with `\foreach` command and simply copy-pasting
but neither one has succeeded.

One entry consist of multiple different elements from table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like ...

```
% create a dummy file with some values
\begin{filecontents}{param.txt}
    0.1 0.2 0.3
    0.4 0.5 0.6
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
            % read the data table
            \pgfplotstableread{param.txt}{\myparams}
        \begin{axis}
            % create a loop and specify some indices that can be found
            % in the data file
            \foreach \i/\j in {
                0/0,
                1/1,
                0/2%
            }{
            % read the element in the data table and store it in `\param'
                    \pgfplotstablegetelem{\i}{\j}\of{\myparams}
                    \pgfmathsetmacro{\param}{\pgfplotsretval}
            % now create the plot and the corresponding legend entry
                \addplot {\param};
                \addlegendentryexpanded{%
                    \pgfmathprintnumber[precision=5,use comma]{\param}
                }
            }
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: +1: This is a very powerful and elegant approach. I will try to use it in my real-world problem. If you have another answer that also uses parameters stored in a file, then please give me a pointer.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner, thanks. If I have another answer like this I am not aware of it right now ... Sorry.

Comment: Note for myself, related question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/292535